# Conditions for convergence of moments

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, uniform-integrability

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of r.v. such that $X_n\xrightarrow [d]{}X$, with $E(X)$ finite, and with $E(|X_n|^{1+\delta})\leq K<\infty$ for all $n$.

We know that:

a) For $\delta>0$, we have $E(|X_n|^{1+\delta})=(1+\delta)\int^{\infty}_0x^{\delta}P(|X_n|>x)dx$

b) For $M,\delta>0$, we have $\int^M_0P(|X_n|>x)dx\leq E(|X_n|)\leq \int^M_0P(|X_n|>x)dx+\int^{\infty}_M\left(\frac{x}{M}\right)^{\delta}P(|X_n|>x)dx$

Now I'm supposed to be able to prove that $E(|X_n|)\rightarrow E(|X|)$ and $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)$

I was trying to use $$|E(|X_n|)-E(|X|)|= \left|\int^M_0P(|X_n|>x)-P(|X|>x)dx + \int^{\infty}_M P(|X_n|>x)-P(|X|>x)dx\right|$$
$$\leq \underbrace{\int^M_0|P(|X_n|>x)-P(|X|>x)|dx }_{\rightarrow 0 \text{ as n goes to } \infty}+\left|\int^{\infty}_M P(|X_n|>x)-\int^{\infty}_MP(|X|>x)dx\right|$$

However, I'm not sure on how to deal with the 2nd term of this RHS and with b). Aren't each of the integrals finite? Couldn't I just apply $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$? But then why would I need b)?

But otherwise, if I bounded it by $\int^{\infty}_M \left(\frac{x}{M}\right)^{\delta} |P(|X_n|>x)-P(|X|>x)|dx$, how would it help me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that it suffices to show that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n) \to \mathbb{E}(X). \tag{1}$$

Then it follows from the triangle inequality that

$$|\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)-\mathbb{E}(|X|)| \leq \mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|) \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, \, n \to \infty,$$

i.e. $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|) \to \mathbb{E}(|X|)$. So let's prove $(1)$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. We have

$$\begin{align*} |\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| &= \left| \int_0^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x) -\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)) \, dx \right| \\ &\leq \int_0^M |\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x)-\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq x)| \, dx + \int_M^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x) + \int_M^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq x) \, dx\\ &= I_1+I_2+I_3 \end{align*}$$

for any $M>1$. We estimate the terms separately. Since $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ is finite, we can choose $M \geq M_1$ sufficiently large such that $I_3 \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. For the second term, note that

$$ \int_M^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x) \leq \frac{1}{M^{\delta}} \int_0^{\infty} x^{\delta} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x) \, dx \leq \frac{K}{M^{\delta} (1+\delta)}.$$

This means that $I_2 \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ for $M \geq M_2$ sufficiently large. Now fix $M \geq \max(M_1,M_2)$. Since $X_n \to X$ in distribution, we have $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x) \to \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq x)$ for (Lebesgue-)almost all $x$. Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\int_0^M |\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq x)-\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq x)| \, dx \to 0 \qquad \text{as}\,\, n \to \infty.$$

Consequently, we find

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| \leq 0 + \frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \frac{2}{3} \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| = 0.$$

Comment: Many thanks for your interest in this question. I still have some doubts on how you take care of the second term. Could you please elaborate on that? This exercise is supposed to solved without using measure theory. So, I'm not sure if I can use what you're suggesting...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. That's funny - solving measure theory problems without using measure theory. Anyway, I have added some more hints.

Comment: this exercise is taken from Keith Knight - Mathematical Statistics. And nowhere in the book is measure theory used. 
But even if measure theory could be used, I would still have a doubt. For $I_2, I_3$ you took M to be as big as one would need, i.e., you took $\lim_{M\to \infty}$, and for $I_1$ you took $\lim_{N\to \infty}$. Would the dominated conv. theorem also work with $\int^{\infty}_0|P(|X_n|>x)-P(|X|>x)|$ ? And which measurable function would you use for 'upperbounding' |P(|X_n|>x)| ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I fix $M$ sufficiently large such that $I_2$ and $I_3$ are small (in the sense that $I_2<\varepsilon/3$, $I_3 < \varepsilon/3$). For this fixed (!) $M$ I can apply the dominated convergence theorem for the first term. And no, you cannot simply apply dominated convergence for $\int_0^{\infty} \dots$ because there is no "upperbounding" function, as you call it. (And sorry, but even if the book doesn't use the words "measure theory" it is still measure theory.)

Comment: but what you're doing by taking the M suff. large for $I_2<\epsilon/3$ is taking the limit w.r.t. M and saying it goes to zero...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. No, $M$ is simply a parameter and I choose it sufficiently large. That's not the same as letting $M \to \infty$.

Comment: Then, how do you prove that $I_2,I_3$ go to zero??

Comment: As I said, I can choose $M$ sufficiently large such that $I_2$ and $I_3$ are small. But choosing something sufficiently large is not the same as letting something to infinity.

Comment: But then, $I_2, I_3$ cannot go as small as you want...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I have extended my answer. Note that it suffices for (fixed but arbitrary!) $\varepsilon>0$ to show that $I_2,I_3 \leq \varepsilon/3$.

Comment: So, what you do is first take $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ and then $\lim_{M\to \infty}$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Sorry, but there is nothing left to say. I do not let $\lim_{M \to \infty}$!

Comment: If I may... the answer shows that for every fixed $M$, $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| \leqslant\frac{K}{M^\delta(1+\delta)}+\int_M^\infty P(|X|\geqslant x)\mathrm dx.$$ If the RHS (depending on $M$) could be made as small as desired, this would imply that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| \leqslant0,$$ that is, that $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to\mathbb{E}(X)$, right? So, the missing piece is simply that $$\inf_{M\gt0}\left(\frac{K}{M^\delta(1+\delta)}+\int_M^\infty P(|X|\geqslant x)\mathrm dx\right)=0,$$ right? OP: can you show this last assertion?

Comment: @Did, Many thanks Did for your help. Now I think I understand what saz was trying to do. I guess I can prove that last assertion since we're assuming the $E(X)$ is finite. I never would have guessed that the answer would involve this lim sup, just by following the book. 
Did, from the wikipedia, if the index for lim sup in n, then the index for the inf should be $n>0$, no?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: The infimum in my comment is definitely over $M\gt0$. Your last comment makes me wonder whether you understood what I explained.

Comment: According to wikipedia $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n= \inf_{n\geq0} \sup_{m\ge n}X_n$.

Is the infimum you're using supposed to the inf in the definition of lim sup?

Comment: @Did Thanks for your help...

Comment: The infimum is on $M$, this is what the subscript means. It has nothing to do with a limit or a liminf when $n\to\infty$. To denote an infimum on $n$, one writes $\inf\limits_n$, not $\inf\limits_{M\gt0}$ (not to mention that an infimum on $n$ at this place in my comment would be absurd).

Comment: @saz Well, it seems I am failing spectacularly in getting the point through... :-(

Comment: @Did I wouldn't say spectacularly, since now I think I got it. Thank you for having kept up with me, and helping me out.

P.S: I would like to ask something else, but I'm afraid it would test your patience. But if you're ok, I'll ask in another comment... :)